# Login Required Decorator and Django Session

Tags: python, django

I am logging in as an user by session in  django, i use file to save session. When a user logs in, it creates a session and when it logs out it deletes the session, i want to stop user accessing 'urls' which will be available only after login.But when i use login required it doesn't recognize  'logged in user session' and redirects me to the home page when because i have given `login_url = 'home'` in login_required decorator while defining a function. So how can i make my decorator to recognize logged in session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why logged in user session is not recognized when using login required decorator. You can use the following decorator to access the session, user and the redirects.

```
def custom_login_required(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        session = request.session # this is a dictionary with session keys
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            # the decorator is passed and you can handle the request from the view
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect('login')


    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot fpr the answer, btw if i type request.user while being in session it shows me anonymous user, no i think my request.user is not recognizing my session!

Comment: If the user is anonymous, then the user is not logged in. Try to manually login the user and the check the status. ie login(request, user) and check whether user.is_authenticated == True and user.is_anonymous == False.

Comment: i did it by saving username in session during login, so if username in session then keep on surfing, but if not in session then it would redirect back to home page to login or register.

Comment: Btw may I know more about why and what file your are using to save the session.

Comment: I'm using  `"django.contrib.sessions.backends.file"` to save data